# JUnit error while casting to byte?

Tags: java, junit, casting, byte, assertion

I've written a simple algorithm that converts a binary number in String format to an array of Bytes. I use int's to calculate the numerical value for 8 bits, then cast it into byte.

The problem appears when I run the following code in JUnit:

```
assertEquals( new byte[] {(byte) 0} , Set1.binToBytes("00000000") );
```

So a string with 8 zeros should result in a 0 byte. It ends with an AssertionError. When tracing the variables during debugging, I found the following:

Expected: [0]
Actual: [0]

Is it an error in JUnit, or I messed up something? Are the two above in different types?

After running the whole JUnit test, I found the following error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<[B@65e2dbf3> but was:<[B@4f970963>
```

Comment: Equals (and assertEquals) do not check for array equality: `arr1.equals(arr2)` will only be true iff `arr1 == arr2`.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays don't override the `equals` method. You shouldn't use `assertEquals` to compare arrays. Instead, you should use [`assertArrayEquals`](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Assert.html#assertArrayEquals(byte%5B%5D%2C%20byte%5B%5D)):

```
assertArrayEquals( new byte[] {(byte) 0} , Set1.binToBytes("00000000") );
```

Comment: You mean I shouldn't use assertEquals.

Answer (score 1):

Another option: simply turn to the **one** assert one really needs: **[assertThat](https://objectpartners.com/2013/09/18/the-benefits-of-using-assertthat-over-other-assert-methods-in-unit-tests/)**

This assert works with Hamcrest matchers; so you can write down code like:

```
assertThat(actual, is(expected))
```

And the nice thing ... as long as `actual` and `expected` have matching types (simple objects, arrays, collections, you-name-it) ... the above code will do exactly what you think it should do.

And it gives you a nice clear error message containing both arrays in case they do not match up!

As soon as you get used to it; you will find that there is no need any more to use any other variation of assert.